# Filter lists by discarding sublists that contain integers different from 0 or 1

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Imagine I have a list of the type

```
Lst = {{1,0,1,1},{4,0,1,1}, {1,1,0,0},{2,1,1,1},{0,0,0,1}}
```

I want to select only those sublists that only contain elements   0 or 1. For example for the above list the reduced list which I want is

```
IWantThis = {{1,0,1,1},{1,1,0,0},{0,0,0,1}}
```

Motivation for this is the given situation describes spinless fermions or spin 1/2 objects.

Comment: If the order doesn't matter then `BitAnd[Lst, 1] ⋂ Lst` does it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To filter a list

```
list = {{1, 0, 1, 1}, {4, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
```

you can use `Select` like this:

```
Select[list, ContainsOnly[{0, 1}]]
(* {{1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}} *)
```

This should work with Mathematica 10.2+.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot

Comment: In earlier versions, use `Cases[]` instead: `Cases[list, {(0 | 1) ..}]`.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) and [`Union`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html).

```
Lst = {{1,0,1,1},{4,0,1,1}, {1,1,0,0},{2,1,1,1},{0,0,0,1}};
Select[Lst, Union[#] == {0, 1} &]
```

> {{1,0,1,1},{1,1,0,0},{0,0,0,1}}

I have used [`Union`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html)specifically, because it sorts out the list after removing duplicates unlike [`DeleteDuplicates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 0, 1, 1}, {4, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};

Cases[{OrderlessPatternSequence[0 .., 1 ..]}] @ list
```

{{1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 0, 1, 1}, {4, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
```

Using `Pick` and `MatchQ`:

```
Pick[#, MatchQ[MatchQ[#, 0 | 1] & /@ #, {True ..}] & /@ #] &@list

(*{{1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}*)
```

Comment: It fails if an entry such as `{0.5, 1, 1, 1}` is present. `IntervalMemberQ` seems more suitable for continuous ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, @Syed! Please see the update. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
Select[# == Unitize @ # &] @ Lst == IWantThis
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Using:

```
Lst = {{1, 0, 1, 1}, {4, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0,
```

0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}};

If lists must contain 0 and 1  and no other integers, some variants:

```
Pick[Lst, MinMax[#] == {0, 1} & /@ Lst]
Reap[Sow[#, MinMax[#] == {0, 1}] & /@ Lst, True][[2,1]]
```

both yield: {{1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}

If accepted elements can be all 0 or all 1:

```
Reap[Sow[#, 0 <= Min[#] <= Max[#] <= 1] & /@ Lst, True][[2,1]]
Pick[Lst, 0 <= Min[#] <= Max[#] <= 1 & /@ Lst]
```

yields: {{1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 0, 1, 1}, {4, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0,
     0, 1}};

Select[Sqrt[#] == # &][list]
```

or

```
Cases[list, {Repeated[0 | 1, {1, ∞}]}]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}

---

**Using `ContainsOnly`:**

Select[ContainsOnly[{0, 1}]][list]

**Using `Unitize`:**

Pick[list, Unitize@# == # & /@ list]

*These solution were already posted by @kglr and @JEMMosig and I failed to notice them. My apologies.*